# how to connect android studio with emulator that was built from android source

Tags: android-emulator

i have followed instructions on http://source.android.com/source/building.html and built for lunch option aosp_arm_eng. The emulator that's available as part of the build is loading fine. Now i am unable to find details how i can make my android studio make use of the emualtor images i just built.  Emulator seems to work with AVDs known to it (tools -> android -> AVD manager list) but does not have way to use new images that might have been custom built on the local machine. 
I plan to make some changes to android media framework source(frameworks/av/media), rebuild the system image, make the emulator use updated image, and re-test my application using android-studio.

Comment: i ment "android studio" seems to work with AVDs known to it...

Comment: One would think that if you tried to launch or debug a project, it would be showing you a list of available adb targets, including any running emulators.  Does adb from the command line work with your emulator?

Comment: thank you. yes, it showed and I could connect. The app failed to run as google playservices isn't available on the emulator. when i tried to click the link to install Goog play service, the app stopped.  I am using M (API 23). Looks like getting Google play service working on emulator isn't straight forward. Appreciate if there are any suggestions to address this.